# Mocking Autofac's "Resolve" extension method with TypeMock

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mocking, autofac, typemock

I'm trying to mock an Autofac resolve, such as

```
using System;
using Autofac;
using TypeMock.ArrangeActAssert;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inst = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IContainer>();
        Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(ResolutionExtensions), Members.ReturnNulls);
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => inst.Resolve<IRubber>()).WillReturn(new BubbleGum());
        Console.Out.WriteLine(inst.Resolve<IRubber>());
    }
}

public interface IRubber
{}

public class BubbleGum : IRubber
{}
```

Coming from Moq, the syntax and exceptions from TypeMock confuse me a great deal. Having initially run this in a TestMethod, I kept getting an exception resembling "WhenCalled cannot be run without a complementing behavior". I tried defining behaviors for everyone and their mothers, but to no avail.

Then I debug stepped through the test run, and saw that an actual exception was fired from Autofac: IRubber has not been registered.

So it's obvious that the static Resolve function isn't being faked, and I can't get it to be faked, no matter how I go about hooking it up.

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => ResolutionExtensions.Resolve<IRubber>(null)).WillReturn(new BubbleGum());
```

... throws an exception from Autofac complaining that the IComponentContext cannot be null. Feeding it the presumably faked IContainer (or faking an IComponentContext instead) gets me back to the "IRubber not registered" error.

Answer (score 2):

This might be one of those cases of swimming against the tide - the amount of code required to create a 'real' container, with the appropriate dependency registered, is less or similar to the configuration for TypeMock. I'd suggest going down that path.

Instead of having the target component depend on IContainer at all, you could instead use 'Relationship Types' like Func, which are implicitly supported by Autofac and more expressive, in addition to being easily mockable. http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/ has more information on that approach, as does http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories.

Comment: How would you mock Owned<T> though?

Comment: It is usally possible to treat `Owned<T>` as though it is a basic type like `List<T>` or `string` - construct values of `Owned<T>` using its constructor when you need it, possibly passing a mock for the `T` instance. Hope this helps.

Comment: For the lifeTime ctor parameter of the Owned<T> class, is it fine to just pass in a mock of IDisposable? What should truly be passed as that param? Thanks!

Comment: A mock is fine. In tests I've created, I often use a stub implementation of `IDisposable` that reveals an `IsDisposed` property - then the test can check to make sure the owned instance was properly released.